# .Net Bing Map soap service limit

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, routes, bing-maps

Do you know, if the bing map soap service using has daily limit? 
For example daily query is 1.000

I am using route service for calculate ways and distances between cities.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

> “Evaluation [...] for a 90 day evaluation period without entering into an Agreement, provided that (i) your use is consistent with the terms of Section 7; and (ii) you do not exceed **10,000 transactions** of any type including sessions as defined in the SDKs, whether billable or non-billable, in any 30 day period."
>
> “Limited Commercial, Non-Commercial or Government Use” [...] provided that (i) your use is consistent with the terms of Section 6; (ii) your Company Application is publically available without restriction  (for example, login or password must not be required and it must not be located behind a firewall); and (iii) you do not exceed either **125,000 transactions of type session or 500,000 transactions of any type**, whichever comes first, both as defined in the SDKs, in any twelve month period.

source: [Microsoft® Bing™ Maps Platform APIs’ Terms Of Use](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/product/terms.html)